# RNCryptor "encryptData" returning null

Tags: ios, objective-c, encryption, rncryptor

New to iOS dev, trying to work on encoding data for secure data storage in db.

I found the current example here: https://github.com/RNCryptor/RNCryptor-objc

This is my code.

```
NSString * aPassword =@"tempkey";

NSData *data = [@"Data" dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
NSError *error;
NSData *encryptedData = [RNEncryptor encryptData:data
                                    withSettings:kRNCryptorAES256Settings
                                        password:aPassword
                                           error:&error];


NSLog(@"Data: %@", [[NSString alloc] initWithData:encryptedData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]);
```

My log

```
2016-10-20 11:41:52.662 BlueBoard[57245:10027277] Data: (null)
```

Am I missing a step in this process? I've confirmed that it's null because it the db its being stored as null as well.

Comment: Use the `error` parameter to see what went wrong.

Comment: `encryptedData` isn't nil. Your mistake is trying to convert `encryptedData` into an `NSString`. `encryptedData` is not UTF-8 encoded string data.

Comment: @AndyIbanez I did have the error check present and it was not printing an error.

Comment: @rmaddy How can I determine what encoding it is in?

Comment: @rmaddy is right. This is not an encoded string. You cannot convert it a string because it isn't one. If your intention is to print the encrypted blob, just print the `encryptedData` itself. I'm not sure why you would want to do that, but if you want to see something, that's the way to go.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your issue isn't that `encryptedData` is `nil`, it's that you are attempted to create an `NSString` from data that doesn't represent a string.

If you wish to convert `encryptedData` into a string for storage or other purposes, you should convert the data into a Base 64 encoded representation. Do this with the `base64EncodedStringWithOptions:` method.

```
NSString *base64String = [encryptedData base64EncodedStringWithOptions:0];
```

Of course when you want to decrypt the string later, you will need to convert the Base 64 encoded string back into `NSData`, and then decrypt that data.

Comment: I suspected it had something to do with encoding before you mentioned in a comment earlier but I wasn't sure how to determine what encoding. Thank you for your help!